# Need ClearenceAbout Old Answers

Tags: support

My account was almost blocked in the past due to a answers in the past that **i do not remember anything about it**, i have been asked if it was a network, does that mean that my company network, and if is it so could some one **hacked** to my account from my company and answered those answers and how i can see those deleted answers?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that someone hacked into your account only to post some bad answers that would get you blocked. More likely, the issue is that of a shared IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather unlikely that your account was hacked and the hacker used it to post answers.

But you can view your deleted answers from the past 60 days. Perhaps that will refresh your memory.

1. Go to your user profile page (click on your user icon at the top of the page).
2. In the "Answers" section, click on the link that says "view more".
3. At the bottom of the next page, click on the link that says "deleted recent answers".

You'll end up at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/2128706).

Comment: the problem is the answers were before a year @Cody Gray

Comment: You will need a moderator to help you with that, then. Perhaps one will see this question.

Comment: how i can find one? @Cody Gray